# Unix To display student records

Tags: unix

Contents of sample input file(input.txt) - starting from following line,

```
Name|Class|School Name
Deepu|First|Meridian
Neethu|Second|Meridian
Sethu|First|DAV
Theekshana|Second|DAV
Teju|First|Sangamithra
```

I need to output the details of the student with the school name Sangamithra
in the below format. I am new to unix. So I need help.

Desired output:

```
Sangamithra|First|Teju
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in the output, this can be achieved using `grep`:

```
grep "Sangamithra" input.txt
```

If you want the name to be first, you might need `awk` (tested):

```
grep "Sangamithra" input.txt | awk -F "|" '{print $3"|"$1"|"$2}'
```

Comment: You want to avoid the [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: A proper solution should only examine the first field, though (which of course is another reason to do this in pure Awk).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking something like this one.

```
awk -F\| '{print $3"|"$2"|"$1}' filename
School Name|Class|Name
Meridian|First|Deepu
Meridian|Second|Neethu
DAV|First|Sethu
DAV|Second|Theekshana
Sangamithra|First|Teju
```